# unknown circuit symbol rectangle with arrow

Tags: symbol, diagram

I've never seen this symbol before but my wiring diagram is full of it. I also have searched for lists of symbols but it isn't among them. Does anybody know what is is? It is from my wiring diagram of a Yamaha RS 125.
https://pasteboard.co/HX0dVKZ.jpg
(the image was to large so i uploaded it to pasteboard so it wouldn't get compressed)

But this is the symbol in question.

[image: Symbol]

Comment: Please put a cropped photo of the symbol into your question so that readers don't have to follow a link to understand your question.

Comment: I don't think low rep users have priv for adding images. Please reconsider the down votes.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Are you [sure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/294404)?

Comment: New user should be able to add two images and two links. I didn't downvote.

Comment: Ooops, haven't tried to post a photo as a new member since early on, when it was still verbotten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's non-standard. But I've seen similar symbols before that were for single-terminal connectors, such as bullet-crimps:

[image: Bullet Crimp Connector/Terminal]

Comment: And presumably the triangle represents the pin and the rectangle the socket.

Comment: That certainly sounds logical, but I don't have any evidence to add that to the answer.

Comment: I think this would be it indeed. It sounds logical and there are a lot of these connectors in the wiring harness. I'm going with this answer!